# execute several times the same procedure in python

Tags: python, procedure

In my code I'm currently doing something like this:

```
for _ in xrange(n):
    f(x)
```

where `f` is some arbitrary function that does not return anything (ie just a `None`) and `x` is an arbitrary input for this function

I was just wondering whether there is a proper way to do this in one line? There are a lot of functions in python like `map`, `fold`, etc that are used to operate on elements of a list, but all of them seem to consider that we are interested in what the function returns.

Doing:

```
[f(x) for _ in xrange(n)]
```

is actually working fine, but it returns a whole list of `None` that I don't need.

Comment: Since the price of `\n` characters is still 0, it's OK to do this in 2 lines.

Comment: The second one should be avoided because you are using the comprehension for its side-effect, which is a huge [no-no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two lines is fine and expected.

You *could* do `for _ in range(n): f(x)` if you had a good reason, but you probably don't have one of those.

Answer (score 0):

For me, writing something like

```
for i in array: f(x)
```

works in python 2.7 and 3